# How can I get Ad name from Ads API using NPM?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I tried with google ads api npm with the query

`SELECT ad_group_ad.ad.name, ad_group_ad.ad.type , ad_group_ad.ad.app_ad.headlines,ad_group_ad.ad.app_engagement_ad.headlines,ad_group_ad.ad.text_ad.headline
FROM
  ad_group_ad`

Response

`{
  ad: { resource_name: 'customers/xxxxx/ads/xxxxxx', type: 3 },
  resource_name: 'customers/xxxxx/adGroupAds/xxxx~xxxxxx
}`

But response not containing ad name. 
Ad Id and resource name is there.

How can I get the ad name?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC at least in the Adwords API (the Ads API's predecessor), only image ads have a name.

It might be worthwile to run your query on an account where image ads are present (`ad_group_ad.ad.type = IMAGE_AD`) and see whether your response contains the `ad.name` field in that scenario.